# Há alguma relação entre estes dois elementos do código HTML?

Tags: java, html

Estou a retirar dados de um site com o *Jsoup* mas eu não sou muito bom em *html*. Gostaria de saber se neste site existe alguma relação entre *".lin-area-c2"* e *".lin-curso-c3"*.

Se houver, gostaria de saber como usá-la para colocá-los numa *arrayList*, por exemplo, já que da maneira que eu estou a fazer primeiro faz *extract* dos *".lin-area-c2"* e depois dos *".lin-curso-c3"* (gostaria de fazer sequencialmente).

No geral, extrai um *".lin-area-c2"* e depois se após tiver um *".lin-curso-c3"*, é extraído também.

Obrigado!

[Aqui esta](http://www.dges.gov.pt/guias/indcurso.asp?letra=A) o link do site.

```
Document document = null;

document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.dges.gov.pt/guias/indcurso.asp?letra=E").get();

for(int contador=0;contador<document.select(".lin-area-c2").size();contador++) {
    Log.d("tag",""+ document.select(".lin-area-c2").get(contador).text());
}

for(int contador=0;contador<document.select(".lin-curso-c3").size();contador++){
    Log.d("tag",""+ document.select(".lin-curso-c3").get(contador).text());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O `box10` é a categoria do curso, o `lin-curso` é a linha com os dados do curso e as classes `lin-curso-c1`, `lin-curso-c2`, `lin-curso-c3`, `lin-curso-c4` são as colunas com as informações do curso. Ele monta uma tabela utilizando divisores ao invés de usar uma tabela.

Comment: Ha alguma maneira de selecionar selecionar apenas lin-curso-c3 e Lin-area-c2?